# What's "ancient time"?

Tags: manifolds

I've found a reference to "ancient time" from Google.

It's mentioned in e.g. the book [Sobolev Inequalities, Heat Kernels under Ricci Flow, and the Poincare Conjecture, by Qi S. Zhang](https://books.google.fi/books?id=sQEbzCJ1DzAC&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=manifold%20has%20positive%20section%20curvature%20very%20ancient%20time&source=bl&ots=2gY_W0xfO9&sig=vSX6KR1O3ozfcDYSdU0pcvSEW4M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb86PpurfJAhWB2ywKHe7cCvIQ6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=manifold%20has%20positive%20section%20curvature%20very%20ancient%20time&f=false).

E.g.

> The second case is when the manifold $M$ is compact and has positive sectional curvature everywhere. Let $t_0$ be a very ancient time.

What's "ancient time" and why is the name such?

Comment: It's talking about ancient solution to the Ricci flow, which is a family $\{g_{ij}(t): t\in (-\infty, c]\}$ of Riemannian metric on $M$ so that $\partial_t g_{ij} = 2\text{Ric}(g).$ I believe by very ancient time it means just a very negative $t$.

Comment: I wonder if the "very" qualifier makes it even something more different than just "ancient time"?

Comment: http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/and-did-those-feet-in-ancient-time/